# <tr> background color only changes on even childs

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Try to click on any table row, it will only black highlight the even ones, what did I miss?
It was supposed to turn row backgrounds black, on click.
Here's my current code:
**HTML:**

```
<div class="table-responsive">
    <table id="tEmprego" class="table table-striped table-hover">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>#</th>
          <th>Table heading</th>
          <th>Table heading</th>
          <th>Table heading</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>Table cell</td>
          <td>Table cell</td>
          <td>Table cell</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>Table cell</td>
          <td>Table cell</td>
          <td>Table cell</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>3</td>
          <td>Table cell</td>
          <td>Table cell</td>
          <td>Table cell</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>4</td>
          <td>Table cell</td>
          <td>Table cell</td>
          <td>Table cell</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.table-hover>tbody>tr:hover>td, .table-hover>tbody>tr:hover>th {
  background-color: #550055;
  color:#eeeeee;
}

.hovered{
   background-color: #000000;
  color:#ffffff;
}
```

**Javascript:**

```
$("#tEmprego").on('click','td',function() {
       $(this).closest("tr").siblings().removeClass("hovered");
       $(this).parents("tr").addClass("hovered");
});
```

**Bootply:**
http://www.bootply.com/28I0IItFmP

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The cause of it is that your css rules from bootstrap is being applied to `td`s, while your `.hovered` is being applied to `tr`.

Basically, when you click on it, you have grey table cells (`td`) over a black row (`tr`). You also need more weight on your selector, since `.hovered` is too weak and it's going to be overwritten by other rules (avoid using `!important`, or you could get on an infinite `!important` css war!):

```
.table-hover tbody tr.hovered td {
    background-color: #000000;
    color: #ffffff;
}
```

Also, you don't necessarily need to add `>` selectors to make the hover effect, unless you have other tables inside that one. Another thing is that your `th` are inside a `thead`, not `tbody`:

```
.table-hover tbody tr:hover td, .table-hover thead tr:hover th {
    background-color: #550055;
    color: #eeeeee;
}
```

Here's a fixed fork for your code:

http://www.bootply.com/mwFvWpMiGa

Answer (score 5):

Your `tr` background color is being overwritten in favor of a more specific rule specific in Bootstrap that is only applied to odd-numbered rows:

```
.table-striped>tbody>tr:nth-child(odd)>td, .table-striped>tbody>tr:nth-child(odd)>th {
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
}
```

You'll need to write a more specific rule for your table cells rows e.g.:

```
   .table-striped tbody tr.hovered td {
       background-color: #000000;
       color:#ffffff;
    }
```

http://www.bootply.com/yptfNtx2iN

Answer (score 4):

Your `.table-striped` class is causing this.

One option is to simply remove it.

#### [Bootply Demo](http://www.bootply.com/8n7N8DJ1ck)

Comment: More specifically, the `tr` IS getting the black styling, but the white is coming from a `.table-striped>tbody>tr:nth-child(odd)>td` selector in bootstrap.min.css. Your `td`s are white, and covering your `tr`s

Comment: Thx for the additional explanation!

Answer (score 4):

**Bootply** : http://www.bootply.com/vMiwF3v4cl

**CSS**:

```
.hovered td {
   background-color: #000000 !important;
   color:#ffffff !important;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this one -  is that what you meant http://www.bootply.com/t7fsAfqZDp ?

```
$(document).on('click',"#tEmprego",function() {
//click on whole table
  $(this).find('tr').filter(function(item){
//get tr's and filter only odd/even ones
          return $(item).index() % 2
  }).toggleClass("hovered");
//change class on them
});
```

Comment: You should include relevant code in your answer too.

Answer (score 3):

There is a class in `bootstrap.min.css`:

```
.table-striped>tbody>tr:nth-child(odd)>td, .table-striped>tbody>tr:nth-child(odd)>th {
     background-color: #f9f9f9;
}
```

This one set `background-color` to odd td's.

Answer (score 1):

you have to set a class (eg: selected) in the click event of each rows to that row. then also add more specific css style for each td.

here you define: find a table with .table and table-striped class and inside rows with .selected class and set background-color of inner td to specified color:

```
table.table.table-striped tr.selected td {
    background-color: #color;
}
```